# Running Django with Gunicorn over Nginx in Kubernetes is a good idea?

Tags: django, nginx, kubernetes

I created Django site and expecting a lot of processing on my site.
I'm running `Nginx` server with `Gunicorn` as explained in [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dajngo-with-nginx-gunicorn-aaf8431dc9e0) tutorial

I would like to make something `scalable` to be able to raise processing power on my site.
I have a simple question. Is it possible to move this `severs-lump` into `kubernetes`? And if yes, is it a good idea? Or should I use `nginx` with `uWSGI` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to move `servers-lamp` into Kubernetes.

Yes, it is a good idea however it depends on you and your organisation's policies.

In Kubernetes, you can use Nginx ingress controller and run Gunicorn, uWSGI. We are running a flask with Gunicorn on K8s along with an Ingress controller so far it's working well.

You can refer to this article also: https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-guide-to-deploy-flask-app-on-google-kubernetes-engine-bfbbee5c6fb

Comment: thanks for the explanation! My organization has own servers, so I will probably creating the Kuberenets by myself, do you think it easier to apply it for Gunicorn or uWSGI?

Comment: Yes it's easy however inside docker you can run single process also with `python run.py`